# "Folding" in Eclipse doesn't work with object parameter (javascript files)

Tags: javascript, eclipse, folding

I'm using Eclipse Luna, and in javascript files the "folding" feature doesn't work for objects that are passed as paraemters.
Consider the following coding:

```
// Folding works
function test() {

}

//Folding works fine...
var blub = {
    // Folding works fine...
    test: function() {
    }
}

somecomponent.extend("bla.blub.test", {

    // Folding doesn't work
    setData : function(value) {
        this._data = value;
        return;
    },

    /*
    * Folding doesn't work...
    * 
    */
    getData : function(value) {
        return this._data;
    }
})
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: try to complete the parenthesis of `extend` function? Sometimes IDE requires valid syntax to make folding available

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, function was closed, copy/paste mistake...